# How to build MySQL query to select between 2 product prices

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a  eCommerce site, where I need to get the products between 2 price points

I am using the following MySQL query for selecting between multiple price points
[image]

```
$select_query = "select * from product where `enabled`='1' and `price` between '" . $min_price  .  "' and '" . $max_price . "'";
```

I would like to extend this query, where I need to select products between 2 price points :

1. Select All the products which costs below 50
2. Select All the products which costs between 100 and 150
3. Select All the products which costs above 200

Any idea, how to build such a query?

Comment: You can prepare SQL statement with multiple where clause with OR

Comment: as one more option, you can have multiple selects having single where condition & at bottom you can Union all records

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommend to use PHP variables to use in query.

When there is one point to range, it needs two variables (`$min_price` and `$max_price`).
Now there are two ranges, so use four variables to store the range(`$min_price1`,`$min_price2`,`$max_price1`, and `$max_price2`).

First store the ranges to these variables. Refer this page [PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes](http://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/).

[Note: *if the first option is checked, then take* `$min_price1 = 0` *and* `$max_price1 = 50`*. Also take care for the last option*]

And now the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE enabled='1' 
AND ( ( price  BETWEEN $min_price1 AND $max_price1 ) OR ( price BETWEEN $min_price2 AND $max_price2 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the selected conditions to the where clause with OR condition as you a have check box

```
select * 
from product
where enabled='1' 
and ( price <50 or (price between 100 and 150) or price >200)
```

Comment: and what if one box of "above 150" is also checked? Will you change query again & again?

Comment: @AK47, not sure about php, i thought we can construct query on the fly based on the optins selected.

Comment: that is what my point is you have written query directly. there should be query which will have dynamic like syntax. Currently your answer is only for the condition which user have mentioned in question. But in broader scenario more filter/conditions will come in picture.